# Jquery, how to work with high numbers

Tags: jquery, numbers

I need to validate some integer number which is 22 chars long. I need to divide that number and get quotient as well as remainder of divining. BUT, when I send it to modulo function, it returns 7.04406000774059e+21

```
labas = modulo(7044060007740589212932, 97);
function modulo (divident, divisor){
alert(divident);
}
```

Comment: thats a big number, javascript won't handle it [see this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/1986499)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of libraries for handling big numbers in js:

- [biginteger](https://github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger) (and [description](http://silentmatt.com/biginteger/))
- [bignumber](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber)
- [jsbn](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/)
- [bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean **divide** (not "divine") and **remainder** (not "bad part").
I rolled some funny dice to get a random number (8233), which I will use for some examples.
* When you divide 8233 by 8, the remainder is 1. `8233 = (8 * 1029) + 1`
* When you divide 8233 by 9, the remainder is 7. `8233 = (9 * 914) + 7`
* When you divide 8233 by 10, the remainder is 3. `8233 = (10 * 823) + 3`
* When you divide 8233 by 11, the remainder is 5. `8233 = (11 * 748) + 5`

To answer your question:
When dealing with numbers in JavaScript, you must remember that only the first fifteen or sixteen digits are good. If the number has more digits, the results usually will not be exact.
Your example uses this number: `7044060007740589212932`
JavaScript cannot deal with that number exactly. The best it can do is `7044060007740589735936`, which is `523004` too high. But you don't want `7044060007740589735936`, you want `7044060007740589212932`.
Here is a workaround:
Keep your number as a *string*, not as a number.
`"7044060007740589212932"`
Then separate the string into two parts, right in the middle.
`"70440600077"` and `"40589212932"`
Now you have two strings, each containing eleven digits.
Then do this:
`parseInt("70440600077", 10)` gets you the number `70440600077`
`(70440600077 % 97)` gets you the number `36`
Notice that `(97 * 726191753) + 36 = 70440600077`
Then take the `36` and do this:
`(36 + "40589212932")` gets you the string `"3640589212932"`
(A number plus a string does a string concatenation.)
`parseInt("3640589212932", 10)` gets you the number `3640589212932`
`(3640589212932 % 97)` gets you the number `0`, which is your end result.
Notice that `97 * 37531847556 = 3640589212932` exactly.

```
72619175300000000000 * 97 =  7044060004100000000000
         37531847556 * 97 =           3640589212932
====================         ======================
72619175337531847556 * 97 =  7044060007740589212932
```

And there you go.